# ansible authorized_key module overwrite the original file

Tags: ansible

I want to add some new pub keys, when use the `authorized_key` module, it seems that ansible overwirte all records.

the tasks:

```
- name: add key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ user if user is defined else 'ubuntu' }}"
    state: present
    key: '{{ item }}'
    exclusive: no
#  comment: "test add comment from playbook"
  with_file:
    - public-keys/test-add.pub
    - public-keys/test-add-doge.pub
```

and the files:

```
roles/add-ssh-key/files/
└── public-keys
    ├── test-add-doge.pub
    └── test-add.pub

1 directory, 2 files
```

`add.yml`:

```
- hosts: '127.0.0.1'
  gather_facts: yes
  remote_user: "{{ user if user is defined else 'ubuntu' }}"
  roles:
   - {role: add-ssh-key}
```

after I executed the playbook `ansible-playbook add.yml`, the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file was overwrited, it only remains 2 records which are `test-add.pub` and `test-add-doge.pub`

So how can I keep original records without overwriting?

Comment: You can use multiple method. read the file and register it for provide old keys in authorized_keys tasks. You can use lineinfile module for add keys. Or you can pass key in single batch on authorized_keys module and don't use loop (best choice).

Comment: "[The `exclusive`] option is not loop aware, so if you use with_ , it will be exclusive per iteration of the loop.  If you want multiple keys in the file you need to pass them all to key in a single batch as mentioned above."  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/authorized_key_module.html